# In VHDL, how do I detect if a binary input is divisible by 3 or 4?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

My code will take input as a binary representation of a number, between 0 and 15 (including both).

My goal is to check if an input is divisible by 3 or 4, if it is: output 1 and implement this function with ***ONLY NOR GATES***.

I have used K-Map method and derived the function formula. Which is the following:
ABCD is my input, 4 bits,

F = (A'+C'+D)(A'+B+C')(A+C+D')(A+B+C'+D)(A+B'+C'+D')(A'+B'+C+D')

I have implemented my formula as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity kod is
   Port ( X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
          O : out  STD_LOGIC);
end kod;

architecture Behavioral of kod is

    -- Following are intermediate signals
    signal CCC : STD_LOGIC;
    signal MMM : STD_LOGIC;
    signal EEE : STD_LOGIC;
    signal RRR : STD_LOGIC;
    signal TTT : STD_LOGIC;
    signal DDD : STD_LOGIC;

begin

    CCC <= NOT ((NOT X(3)) OR (NOT X(1)) OR X(0)) ;
    MMM <= NOT ((NOT X(3)) OR X(2) OR (NOT X(1))) ;
    EEE <= NOT (X(3) OR X(1) OR (NOT X(0))) ;
    RRR <= NOT (X(3) OR X(2) OR (NOT X(1)) OR X(0));
    TTT <= NOT (X(3) OR (NOT X(2)) OR (NOT X(1)) OR (NOT X(0)));
    DDD <= NOT ((NOT X(3)) OR (NOT X(2)) OR X(1) OR (NOT X(0)));

    O <= NOT (CCC OR MMM OR EEE OR RRR OR TTT OR DDD) ;


end Behavioral;
```

When I simulate my code, I see that all of my signals are uninitialized. When I try to initialize my inputs as:

```
entity kod is
   Port ( X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) := "0000";
          O : out  STD_LOGIC);
end kod;
```

I only get 1 as output. 
Where is my fault and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us your testbench? Your fault cannot be reproduced if we can't see something that can be simulated.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "An implementation may allow, but is not required to allow, a design entity at the root of a design hierarchy to have generics and ports...." and 6.5.6.3 "It is an error if a port of mode in is unconnected (see 6.5.6.3) or unassociated (see 6.5.7.3) unless its declaration includes a default expression (see 6.5.2)." For some VHDL tools supplying a default value to inputs is sufficient as the OP does here. Note that value `"0000"` resulted in an incorrect output on `O`, the focus of the question *Where is my fault and how can I fix it?*

Comment: Initialise your input port in your testbench code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equations accept "0000":

[image: kod_tb.png]

I added a term to exclude "0000" along with a little testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity kod is  -- is x divisble by 3 or 4?
    port (
        x:  in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        o:  out  std_logic
    );
end entity kod;

architecture behavioral of kod is

    -- following are intermediate signals
    signal ccc:    std_logic;
    signal mmm:    std_logic;
    signal eee:    std_logic;
    signal rrr:    std_logic;
    signal ttt:    std_logic;
    signal ddd:    std_logic;

    signal zero:   std_logic;  -- added

begin

    ccc  <= not (not x(3) or             not x(1) or     x(0));
    mmm  <= not (not x(3) or     x(2) or not x(1)            );
    eee  <= not (    x(3) or                 x(1) or not x(0));
    rrr  <= not (    x(3) or     x(2) or not x(1) or     x(0));
    ttt  <= not (    x(3) or not x(2) or not x(1) or not x(0));
    ddd  <= not (not x(3) or not x(2) or     x(1) or not x(0));

    zero <= not (    x(3) or     x(2) or     x(1) or     x(0)); -- added term

    o <= not (ccc or mmm or eee or rrr or ttt or ddd or zero); -- ddd);

end architecture behavioral;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity kod_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of kod_tb is
    signal x:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal o:   std_logic;
begin
DUT: 
    entity work.kod
        port map (
            x => x,
            o => o
        );
STIMULIS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
            x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,4));
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

(Forgive me for removing redundant parentheses and formatting for readability).

That gives:

[image: kod_tb_fixed.png]

Answer (score 1):

If you directly simulate your entity `kod` without specifing a default value for your inputs (like in your first attempt), then the value of input `X` will be "UUUU". The value 'U' is the default value of a signal of type `std_logic`. The type `std_logic` is an enumeration of 9 possible values, e.g., '0' for (strong) logic low and '1' for (strong) logic high. The value 'U' indicates that an signal has not been initialized. Either it has not been assigned yet, or an 'U' has been assigned due to an expression. You can lookup the thruth-table for the boolean operators on `std_logic` in one of the VHDL standards or in the file for the package `std_logic_1164` shipped with your VHDL tool. (For example, it is named `std_1164.vhd` in the Quartus toolchain.)

You can reproduce the observed behaviour with an even more simpler example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test1 is
  port (
    x : in std_logic;
    y : out std_logic);
end test1;

architecture rtl of test1 is
begin
  y <= x;
end rtl;
```

This is the simulation output:

[image: simulation output]

To get rid of the uninitialzed value, you have to specify another default value for `X`. In your example, you specified "0000" for your 4-bit input vector. The output `O` is not undefined anymore. It is wrong ('1') because of a bug in your equations. You can fix it, by extending the last equation to set the output to '0' when the input is all zero as also demonstrated by "user1155120".